# Asynchronous ADO command execution, how to close the connection?

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection, ado

The webapp which I’m working on does some data manipulation at the back-end after a user clicks button. This process takes a long time to complete causing the browser to timeout. Therefore I’ve introduced an asynchronous ADO command which causes the page response immediately while the back-end process keeps running. That page also includes an AJAX call to check the status of the back-end process and when it detects that it is completed another AJAX request gets the result of that process form the back-end. All works as expected.

My question is regarding the ADO connection for this scenario as with the asynchronous execution the connection must not be closed.

Is there a way that I can reference the same connection object from another page (the result page requested by AJAX call) and close it ? Or should I just leave it for the server to kill it off eventually.

I was researching a bit for this answer with no success.

Comment: how exactly do you know when the async command has finished?

Comment: @ulluoink The stored procedure which is executed by the async command updates status table at the end of the transaction and the AJAX call periodically checks that status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can reference the same connection object from
>   another page

How about saving async connection in Session("xxx") variable?

Comment: Normally I wouldn't recommend storing an `ADODB.Connection` in the `Session` object but in this scenario it's the only choice I can see that might work.

Comment: That works however, my concern is that when a user opens another instance of the page reference to the first connection will be broken.